# Can Time.deltaTime reach 0?

Tags: unity-game-engine, timedelta

Here is sample of short code

```
    if (timer < 0)
    {
        timer = cooldown;
    }
    else if (timer > 0)
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (timer == 0)
    {
        print(0);
    }
```

and may be `cooldown = 1`

My question is easy: 
is it possible to reach state `timer == 0` ? 
I mean theoretically is there possibility of hitting precisely 0 with `Time.deltaTime` ? I know it sounds stupid considering size of `float` but still im pretty interested if this scenario could happen.

Comment: What is the idea behind this? It could theoretically happen that the last decrease by `Time.deltaTime` causes `timer` to be 0, yes. Usually, you just decrease the `timer` every Update() by `Time.deltaTime` and see if it has already reached a negative value, checking for exactly `timer == 0f` to be true is a very unlikely event.

Comment: idea is to stop timer if timer reach negative value and reset timer from other event. Its just one of concepts which cross my mind after doing some prototyping for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta time can not be zero. Delta time mean the time difference between last frame and current frame. So theoretically it can't be zero. Maybe your timer variable can be but its really low chance. I assume your timer variable is float so when you check if its 0 its actually 0.000000 (something like that). But your timer variable will decrease like 0.969987 , 0.9525292 , ...... , 0.003284598 and after that it will jump to negative values like -0.01333026. When it becomes a negative value you will miss your third if statement.

```
if (timer <= 0)
{
    timer = cooldown;
    print(0);
}
else if (timer > 0)
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

I believe this is a better solution for your case.

Comment: yes that was exact point. I wanted to miss my third if statement to achieve stopping timer and wait for its restart from outside. Thats why i asked if its possible for my timer to reach 0. Because if it reach 0, my concept will crash. So basically i want only < 0 and > 0 values

Comment: Well its really low chance but theoretically it is possible.

Comment: While your answer is correct for the question. Please keep in mind that setting Time.timeScale = 0; will cause Time.deltaTime will return 0.

I only mention this as this answer comes up for a google search "why is time.deltaTime = 0"